# TYPO3 Femanager Template placeholder condition

Tags: php, templates, if-statement, typo3

I have a quite simple problem. I want to add a Star to an FEManager Inputfield if is required.

I tried:

```
<f:form.textarea
            id="femanager_field_address"
            property="address"
            class="input-block-level"
            additionalAttributes="{femanager:Misc.FormValidationData(settings:'{settings}',fieldName:'address')}"
            additionalAttributes="{ng-model: 'address'}"
            placeholder="{f:translate(key: 'tx_femanager_domain_model_user.address')}{f:if(condition:{femanager:Misc.IsRequiredField(fieldName: 'address', actionName: actionName)} == 1)->f:then('*')" />
</div>
```

But I got a Textbox with the following placeholder:

```
Adresse{f:if(condition:1 == 1)->f:then('*')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{f:if(condition:{femanager:Misc.IsRequiredField(fieldName: 'address', actionName: actionName)} == 1)->f:then('*')
```

That's not a valid Fluid expression. Because of that, Fluid simply interprets what it can (which is the inner `femanager:misc.isRequiredField` ViewHelper, which renders to `1` or more probably `true`).

There are two issues here:

1. When using the `f:if` ViewHelper in its inline notation, simply supply the `then` value as argument to that ViewHelper.

   Example (simplified):

   ```
   {f:if(condition: someVariable, then: '*')}
   ```
2. When using another ViewHelper in the `condition` argument of an `f:if` ViewHelper, it needs to be in a string variable:

   Example:

   ```
   {f:if(condition: "{femanager:misc.isRequiredField(...)}", then: '*')}
   ```